# Wordpress get posts by week with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am displaying Events(custom post type) by week based on a custom field of 'event_date'. I have the initial load working. What it does it gets the start and end of the current week and returns the events that fall within that period of time. What I need to be able to do is click a next or previous button and update the events based on that week(events should be updated via Ajax).

Here is my jQuery click function. It just hits the 'get-events.php' page and appends the data to a div.

```
$('.next-week').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://gwsb-website/wp-content/themes/gwsb/get-events.php",
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
    $('.events-listing').html( html );
  });
});
```

Here is the php in 'get-events.php'

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

// Variables
$day = date('w');
$weekStart = date('Ymd', strtotime('monday this week'));
$weekEnd = date('Ymd', strtotime('sunday this week'));
$currentHeader = '';

query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'      => 'event_date',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'value' => array( $weekStart, $weekEnd ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
));
?>

<?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
    $tempDate = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'event_date', true );
    if ( $tempDate != $currentHeader ) : $currentHeader = $tempDate; ?>
    <h3 class="event-date-header"><?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $currentHeader); echo $date->format('l, F d, Y'); ?></h3>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="event<?php echo the_subcategory_class(); ?>">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php $content = get_the_content(); echo wp_trim_words( $content , '20' ); ?></p>

        <div class="event-meta">
        <?php if (get_field('start_time')) : ?>
            <span><?php the_field('start_time'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (get_field('end_time')) : ?>
            <span> - </span><span><?php the_field('end_time'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?> 

        <?php if (get_field('location')) : ?>
            <span class="dot">&bull;</span><span><?php the_field('location'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!--  .event-meta -->
    </div><!-- .event -->
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: you need the next weeks event or are u suggesting a pagination?

Comment: Yeah, I would need the next week or previous week depending on the link the user clicks. You will be able to cycle through all 52 weeks in the year.

Comment: you can pass prev next week days values for prev and next  and pass it as  GET with your url